# Split by (a), (b), ..., (z)

Tags: python

I have a string and I want to split by these delimiters (a), (b), ..., (z)

```
string="""(a) first string
(b) second (string)
(c) third string"""

string.split("()")
```

What I want:

```
[(a) first string, (b) second (string), (c) third string)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an `re.findall` approach here:

```py
string = """(a) first string
(b) second (string)
(c) third string"""

items = re.findall(r'\([a-z]{1,3}\).*?(?=\s*\([a-z]{1,3}\)|$)', string, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(items)  # ['(a) first string', '(b) second (string)', '(c) third string']
```

Note that here I assume that each bullet would have at most *three* lowercase letters in it.  If not, then it might be hard to distinguish from things like `(string)`, which would appear to also be section headers.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: This is looking good If I want to edit the three lowercase to one Is {1} ok or {1,1}

Comment: Is it possible to exclude the i character from your regex ?

Comment: @ayansalt2 Yes, use `\([a-hj-z]{1,3}\)`